# in 2DPDA and 3DPDA:2 and 3 is the number of tapes or of stacks?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata

I'm struggling with the definitions of the push-down automata. In 2-DPDA and 3-DPDA, what do the numbers 2 and 3 stand for: for the number of stacks or of read-only tapes (and hence RO heads) ?

Finally, is there a language accepted by k-DPDA but not with (k-1)-DPDA for any k ?

It seems that the last question is unsolved (a conjecture by Ibarra-Harrison) as of 1968:

[image]

Comment: Please don't cross post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664072/in-2dpda-and-3dpda2-and-3-is-the-number-of-tapes-or-of-stacks)

Comment: I **had to cross**: I wanted to migrate it as suggested by a comment there but I do not know how.

Comment: Did you understand my answer?

Comment: Yes, I've understood what is says but **not** how is that equivalence for $K\geq 2$ proved. It is stated as a conjecture in my source, is that correct ?

Comment: If you post on the wrong site, please delete the copy on the old site and update your question based on the comments you've received, before posting on a new site.  If you prefer to have it migrated, flag it for moderator attention ("in need of moderator intervention"), explain, and wait for them to act. You should never need to cross-post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K{-}DPDA$ is equivalent to $2{-}DPDA$ for any $K \geq3. $That means for example  $2{-}DPDA$ is capable of do the same work as $3{-}DPDA$ do,  $2{-}DPDA$ is capable of do the same work as $4{-}DPDA$ do etc$.......... ... ... .. .. ..... .. .$

And $K{-}DPDA$ is equivalent to Turing Machine  for any $K \geq2$$.$ $\{a^nb^nc^n\}$ is recognized by $2{-}DPDA$ but not by $1{-}DPDA$ or by $DPDA$ with $1{-}stack.$

---

**Theorem1:-** $\{a^nb^nc^n\}$ is recognized by $2{-}DPDA$.

**Proof:-** Suppose I have an two stacks $S_1$ with stack bottom $Z_0$ and $S_2$ with  stack bottom $Z_1.$ Suppose consider  the string $aabbcc$ is for $\{a^nb^nc^n\}.$

**Step1.** When $a$ will come push onto the stack  $S_1$.

**Step2.** When $b$ will come two things happen.

- push $b$ onto the stack  $S_2.$
- pop **one** $a$ from $S_1$ against **one** $b$.

**Step3.** When $c$ will come, pop **one** $b$ from  $S_2$ against **one** $c.$

**Step4.** If you see finally two stacks $S_1$ with stack bottom $Z_0$ and $S_2$ with  stack bottom $Z_1$ then strings are accepted otherwise rejected.

---

**Theorem2:-** $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n\}$ is recognized by $2{-}DPDA$.

**Proof:-** Suppose I have an two stacks $S_1$ with stack bottom $Z_0$ and $S_2$ with  stack bottom $Z_1.$ Suppose consider  the string $aabbccdd$ is for $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n\}.$

**Step1.** When $a$ will come push onto the stack  $S_1$.

**Step2.** When $b$ will come two things happen.

- push $b$ onto the stack  $S_2.$
- pop  $a$ from $S_1$.

**Step3.** When $c$ will come two things happen.

- push $c$ onto the stack  $S_1.$
- pop **one** $b$ from $S_2$ against **one** $c$.

**Step4.** When $d$ will come, pop **one** $c$ from  $S_1$ against **one** $d.$

**Step5.**  If you see finally two stacks $S_1$ with stack bottom $Z_0$ and $S_2$ with  stack bottom $Z_1$ then strings are accepted otherwise rejected.

---

**So we proved that $K{-}DPDA$ is equivalent to $2{-}DPDA$ for any $K \geq3.$**

**Note1:-** You can easily check  $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n\}$ by  $3{-}stack$ that is your homework.

N. B.- $K{-}DPDA$  means $K{-}stack$ or $K{-}counter$ with $DPDA.$

Comment: Please see my edit. Where is the result of equivalence proved in ?

Comment: For real-time (k+1)-DPDA is better than k-DPDA but k-DPDA have caliber to accept that language that (k+1)-DPDA could do for k>=2.

Comment: Right! But where can I find the hint for a **proof** of this nice result ?

Comment: Could you accept a^nb^nc^n by 2 stack? It's known for you?

Comment: I can believe but I've never seen a proof.

Comment: Just wait for my updated answer. I have been writing.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it the case that it's no longer a conjecture ? Which year is this result from ?

Comment: Please have a look on my updated answer then I will give proof k+1- DPDA is same k-DPDA for k>=2.

Comment: Yes, the proof is quite straightforward. What about the rest and about the year it was proved ? Have you proved also that 1 stack doesn't suffice ?

Comment: After some time I will be updated my answer by proof k+1- DPDA is same k-DPDA for k>=2.

Comment: What do you mean by `some time` exactly ? You do not need to prove it here, a reference will suffice.

Comment: All over internet and books proof are unavailable. Only sipser books has just this statement but not proof. I am having dinner, please give some time.

Comment: Done. Check it.

Comment: I'm now lost in what have you proved: you have only proved that $\{a^nb^nc^nd^n\}$ is recognized by $2-DPDA$ but you haven't proved that it is not recognized by $1-DPDA$ and also not that $2-DPDA$ has the full strength of TM, only that this recognizes this particular language.

Comment: Actually why {a^nb^nc^nd^n} isn't recognize by 1-dpda, you need to understand pda. And that 2−DPDA has the full strength of TM, you need to understand TM. I am not discuss here. It's very basic you could find in wikipedia.

Comment: If it is very basic, so why it was a conjecture in 1968 as stated by Harrison Ibarra **conjecture** ?

Answer (score 0):

Your image comes from M.Li and P.M.B. Vitányi: Kolmogorov Complexity and its Applications, Chapter 4 in Handbook of Theoretical Computer Science, vol. A,  J. van Leeuwen Editor.

Both conjectures mentioned are of the form "(k+1)-head X automata are better than k-head X automata", so we can assume that k refers here to the numbers of heads on the (one-way) input tape of an X automaton. In the case of PDA that means there is only one pushdown stack available, but there are several heads that can read various portions of the input tape.

Note that even a finite state automaton can accept the non-context-free language $\{a^n b^n c^n \mid n\ge 1 \}$ if it has three heads that can move along the input tape. Each head moves to one of the letter segments, and synchronously they verify that the number of letters match.

The Harrison-Ibarra paper, Multi-Tape and Multi-Head Pushdown Automata. Inf. Control. 13(5): 433-470 (1968), is Open Archive, and can be accessed via the DOI: [10.1016/S0019-9958(68)90901-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(68)90901-7)

Here is the conjecture (page 462), with H for `heads', which explicitly proposed languages in the difference between two successive levels of an head-hierarchy:

> Let $|\Sigma|\ge2$, and $c$ a symbol not in $\Sigma$. For each $n\ge
> > 2$, define the following sets: $L_2 = \{ xcx \mid x \Sigma*\}$
> $L_{n+1} = \{xcycx \mid y \in L_n , x \in \Sigma^*\}$ (For example,
> $L_3 = \{ xcycycx \mid x, y \in \Sigma^*\}$ ). Then for each $n\ge 2$,
> $L_n$ is $n$-HDPDA definable but not $(n - 1)$-HPDA definable.

The conjecture is proven by Marek Chrobak, Ming Li:
k+1 Heads Are Better than k for PDAs. J. Comput. Syst. Sci. 37(2): 144-155 (1988) DOI:[10.1016/0022-0000(88)90004-9](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(88)90004-9)

Here a quote from that paper (which matches your image):

> The following language was basically defined by Rosenberg [R] in order
> to show that $k + 1$ heads are better than $k$ heads for finite
> automata 
> $L_b = \{ w_1 \#\dots \# w_b \\\$ w_b \# \dots \#w_1 \mid w_i\in \{0,1\}^* \}$
>
> [...] Amazingly, this language can also be
> used to serve our purpose although the proof technique is new.

The proof technique uses Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: You said Multihead dfa which can recognize $\{a^nb^nc^n\}.$ But multihead dfa  is equivalent to classical dfa which shows contradiction.

Comment: @user19121278 You can read this in the scan provided with the question: "(k+1)-head finite automata are better than k-head finite automata".

Comment: That's true, but multihead dfa is equivalent to classical dfa. But here you are saying opposite. Where I have misunderstood, please guide me.

Comment: "On the other hand, the condition $|u|=|2v|$
is indeed impossible to check for a classical, single tape, finite state automaton." But $|u|=|2v|$ is  possible to implement with single tape classical DFA as like half of language $|u|=|v|?$ Am I correct? – 
For example $\{w1w2||w1|=|w2|\}$
is also regular and could be implemented by DFA. So my question how we implement this by dfa if they are not checked with single tape? This question have been torturing me from long time. Please help. I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: Single head is not equivalent to multihead for finite state automata. See the example: with three heads you can do $\{ a^n b^n c^n \}$ by moving the heads along the three segments. That shows $|u|=|v|$ is not really possible to check *when $u$ and $v$ are given on the input tape*. Note $\{w_1w_2\mid |w_1|=|w_2| \}$ is a degenerate case: one does *not* check the segents separately. Compare with  $\{w_1\# w_2\mid |w_1|=|w_2| \}$. For the "half"-language note that only $w_1$ is on the input tape, the existence of a matching $w_2$ is checked on the states of the automaton, not on the tape-symbols.

Comment: "Single head is not equivalent to multihead for finite state automata.  "----- you mean Single head finite automata with read head isn't equivalent to read multihead  ? Or read/write both?

Comment: The question is about a single read-only one-way tape.

Comment: Is single head read-only equivalent multihead read-only?

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. The question whether k+1-head automata are mote powerful than k-head automata is the result mentioned in the question (and commented on in my answer). That is about single one-way read-only tape. For either finite state or push-down automata. Try accepting $\{ a^nb^n \}$ with a finite state automaton using two heads.

Comment: Not possible to accept $\{a^nb^n\}$ finite automata with two heads because we are only reading  and nothing will performed like writing that means we are not doing counting, so it's impossible to counting equal $a's$ and equal $b's$ and accept $\{a^nb^n\}?$